# Mac OSX CPython ctypes library functionality and correct folder location

Tags: python

I have a question regarding the CPython open-source code. I noticed some CPython libraries are compiled to a directory listed below on a Mac OSX operating system.

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload

Regarding the CPython **ctypes** library. Is this the library that is compiled to the file named **_ctypes.cpython-38-darwin.so**? If so is this the **ctypes** source code for the library in CPython located at [tree/master/Lib/ctypes](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/ctypes) on Github. I am asking this because I am trying to modify the correct source code and learn some things regarding CPython. I am trying to determine if the **cyptyes** library simply is just loading native frameworks and libraries through this, or implementing **ctypes** through something else. Or is it implemented through something like the **types.py** library?

[Reference tree/master/Lib/ctypes/util.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ctypes/util.py)

```
# Line 330
if sys.platform == "darwin":
    print(cdll.LoadLibrary("libm.dylib"))
    print(cdll.LoadLibrary("libcrypto.dylib"))
    print(cdll.LoadLibrary("libSystem.dylib"))
    print(cdll.LoadLibrary("System.framework/System"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many Python libraries, ctypes has both C and Python written parts.

The C module is internal, called _ctypes. Your _ctypes.cpython-38-darwin.so (note the underscore at start) is native code, compiled from the C file at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c

The public interface to it is written in Python, and it has platform dependend code to load native libs from the underlying OS, that code you pasted.

You can see where the module files are using Python itself like this:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.__file__
'C:\\Users\\antont\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\ctypes\\__init__.py'

>>> import _ctypes
>>> _ctypes.__file__
'C:\\Users\\antont\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs\\_ctypes.pyd'
```

That's on windows where the native code lib is a DLL, called .pyd for Python DLLs -- same as .dylib on Mac and .so on Linux and others.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. If on Mac OSX an application is using the **_ctypes.cpython-38-darwin.so** module. Would it be utilizing the Python API module **ctypes** or the underlying C code as in **_ctypes.c**. If you may answer that, it would be great help. I want to make changes, in an already compiled program. By editing the CPython source and copying over the module.

Comment: It uses both. When you import ctypes, you import the py module, which further imports the native `_ctypes` module. Depending on what the changes you want are, you need to touch either one or both. The py side import of the native code is in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py